# Node.js post request on page load

Tags: jquery, node.js

So i have a post request (using express) that adds object to message array and a get request that gets the message array and displays it on the html page. When i load the site it already shows two undefined objects. The post request should only be send on a button click (JQuery). How come i get those undefined object?

Code snippets:

```
app.post('/messages', (req,res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  messages.push(req.body);
  res.sendStatus(200); 
});

$(() => {
    $("#send").click(()=>{
        var message = { name: $("#name").val(), message: $("#message").val()};
        postMessage(message);
    });
    getMessages();
});

function postMessage(message) {
    $.post('http://localhost:3000/messages', message);
}
```

Comment: Please post more code about the GET controller and the html to display objects.

Comment: app.get('/messages', (req,res) => {
    res.send(messages);
});

Comment: <div class="container">
    <br>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class="display-4">Send message</h1>
        <br>
        <input id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
        <br>
        <textarea id="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        <br>
        <button id="send" class="btn btn-success">Send</button>
    </div>
    <div id="messages"></div>
</div>

Comment: Where is `messages` defined?

Comment: It is defined as an empty array in the same file that sets up the get and post requests

Comment: I think it is a browser specifik problem, firefox doesn't send undefined objects, however chrome does